# unable to get clear label text when Printing to a Brother Label Printer from the browser

Tags: browser, printing

to a Brother Label Printer from the browser

I want to print labels to Brother Label Printer from a web browser. I know DYMO has a JavaScript framework that makes printing from the browser simple. But I have customers with a Brother label printer so I need to make it work.

So with Google Chrome as it doesn't seem to print header and footers. I have installed the printer/drivers in my laptop and created a custom paper size which measures 62 mmx 100mm.But the labels text is not so clear.I am getting blur text ,can anyone please help on this ,is there any settings in custom paper to get clear print

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print as you would with a "normal" printer? Because brother has an SDK just like Dymo has. You could use it to directly print from your application to the brother. This would also make it possible to use printer functions like cutting labels after printing.

Here is the link to the FAQ: http://www.brother.com/product/dev/faq/bpac/programming/index.htm

Here is a PDF which explains printing from a webapplication: 
http://download.brother.com/pub/com/dev/pdf/bpac_webapplication_eng.pdf

I don't know which programming language you are using, but I am still looking for a good Javascript and/or PHP solution. But above resources should be a good start for you.